# Check length of string, then pad with space or splice with twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would be like to know if exists a twig function that check a a length of a tring, then, limit the string to the desired length or pad it with spaces.

*I known how to make this using str_pad and substr and writing a new Twig filter*. But I want to known if somebody can do it with existents twig filter/functions

For example (string as var name for commodity)

```
{{ "123123123123123"|filter(5) }}
```

returns "12312"

```
{{ "12"|filter(5) }}
```

returns "12_____" (with _ as space)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `format` filter with a padding & precision modifier:

This example pads up to 10 characters or trims the string to 10 characters:

```
Default, left padding:

Cuts to 10...
Arbitrary character:        {{ "%'_10.10s"|format("123123123123123") }}
Space-Padded:               {{ "% 10.10s"|format("123123123123123") }}
Zero-Padded:                {{ "%010.10s"|format("123123123123123") }}

... or expands to 10:
Arbitrary character:        {{ "%'_10.10s"|format("123") }}
Space-Padded:               {{ "% 10.10s"|format("123") }}
Zero-Padded:                {{ "%'010.10s"|format("123") }}

Right padding:

Cuts to 10...
Arbitrary character:        {{ "%'_-10.10s"|format("123123123123123") }}
Space-Padded:               {{ "% -10.10s"|format("123123123123123") }}
Zero-Padded:                {{ "%0-10.10s"|format("123123123123123") }}

... or expands to 10:
Arbitrary character:        {{ "%'_-10.10s"|format("123") }}
Space-Padded:               {{ "% -10.10s"|format("123") }}
Zero-Padded:                {{ "%'-010.10s"|format("123") }}
```

Output:

```
Default, left padding:

Cuts to 10...
Arbitrary character:        1231231231
Space-Padded:               1231231231
Zero-Padded:                1231231231

... or expands to 10:
Arbitrary character:        _______123
Space-Padded:                      123
Zero-Padded:                0000000123

Right padding:

Cuts to 10...
Arbitrary character:        1231231231
Space-Padded:               1231231231
Zero-Padded:                1231231231

... or expands to 10:
Arbitrary character:        123_______
Space-Padded:               123       
Zero-Padded:                0000000123
```

**Note that 0-padding only works from the left, even if you add the alignment modifier**

Edit: [TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ctpkvj)

Comment: This is a good solution. I wonder if the spaces or underlines can be shown "after" the number? as per the example give in the OP's question. Just wondering if that's possible...

Comment: Yes, see the [sprintf](http://www.php.net/sprintf) documentation. I will add such an example to the TwigFiddle.

Comment: Plus 1 for providing a very simple answer and a Twigfiddle to prove it!

Comment: @ccKep It looks like that format counts the total number of characters when adding the underscore. I believe that the original question implies a certain number of underscores. So for 123_______(7 underscores), it should be 123_____ (5 underscores) regardless of the number of characters before it. I could be totally off on a tangent with this one. But that's what I understood of it.

Comment: *So for 123_______(7 underscores), it should be 123_____ (5 underscores)* - I don't understand what you mean by that. They way I understood the question is that OP wants to make sure the string is always exactly X characters long. So either shortened to it (by cutting of the rest) or expanding it by padding a specific character (either on the left or the right).

Answer (score 2):

To get the count in Twig you may attempt this:

```
{% if users|length > 100 %}
    {{ users | truncate(50, true) }}
{% endif %}
```

where users is the variable. In the aforementioned scenario, if the length of users is greater than 100, limit it to 50 characters.

If you want to do that in just one line, try ternary like this:

```
{{ (users|length > 100) ? truncate(50, true) : users }}
```

Note: In order to use truncate, the Text extension may need to be activated. You may be able to activate it, like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
  services:
    twig.extension.text:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Link only answers are somewhat frowned upon.  Perhaps you could update your answer showing how your links can solve the actual question?  Especially the padding part.

Comment: Yes I know this filters, but I have many lines and I dont want to use an if condition for everyone to evaluate length. Is it posible in one line per variable concatenating filters?

Comment: Giancarlo, I have updated the answer to include a one line way to achieve the same result.

Comment: But it doesn't pad with spaces if it is lesser than required lenght

Comment: Giancarlo, I believe that to do it in just one line of code, you will probably need to write a custom filter or a function. May I ask, why not use PHP's str_pad?

Comment: Yes I wrote a custom twig function and it works, but I would like to know if is possible with default twig filters

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer with "standard" Twig functions as requested:

```
{% for i in 0..4 %}
    {{- var|slice(i,1)
    ? var|slice(i,1)
    : '-' -}}
{% endfor %}
```

You can replace `'-'` with a space `' '` as needed.

Here is a Twigfiddle to show it working. I have two samples to see the difference.
https://twigfiddle.com/ioxeh0

Make sure you use the minus signs in the ternary, that removes addtional whitespace. Enjoy!